# The sequence number for the field (ID) was not generating corerct using jquery clone

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Currently working on  jquery clone where when I click `addmore` button from the parent row the id was generating sequence order for the row but not for the inside fields  example 1,2,3,4.. but when i did the inspect element for the fields which is there in the row id was not generating in the sequence order it was coming in the random for example the third row for **txt_Jbt** field the id should come as  **txt_Jbt_3** but currently this is coming as **txt_Jbt_1**

This was code i am using for cloning the field

```
 $(document).on("click", ".test_add_button", function() {
             var $clone = $('.cloned-row2:eq(0)').clone();
            var num = $('.cloned-row2').length;
            $clone.find('[id]').each(function() {
              this.id += '_' + num;
              this.name += '_' + num;
              $clone.addClass("check");
              $(this).removeClass("errRed");    
              $(this).removeClass("required_Field");
            });
            $clone.find('.btn_more').after("<input type='button' class='btn_less1 selbtnless' id='buttonless'/>")
            $clone.attr('id', "select-row" + (count));
            $clone.find(".txt_txtDesc,.txt_scr,.txt_date,.ipt_acdem").val("");
            $clone.find(".txt_txtDesc,.txt_scr,.txt_date,.ipt_acdem").addClass("cloned_field");
            $clone.find("input.txt_date")
              .removeClass('hasDatepicker')
              .removeData('datepicker')
              .unbind()
              .datepicker({
                dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
                changeMonth: true,
                yearRange: "-100:+0",
                changeYear: true,
                maxDate: new Date(),
                showButtonPanel: false,
                beforeShow: function() {
                  setTimeout(function() {
                    $('.ui-datepicker').css('z-index', 99999999999999);

                  }, 0);
                }
              });
            $(this).parents('.sel_text').after($clone);
             $(".cloned-row2").each(function(i){
                    this.id = "select-row"+(i+1);
              });

            add_validation_for_forms();
            additionalvalidation();
          });
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/karthic2914/afzde7ku/4/)

Comment: There is little improvement needed in the idea of cloning and i.e 1. Append new row before "Add More" Button. 2. New Row should contain only "Remove" button and not "Add More" button. 3. If you do not need id's in a sequence that would be easier to just use a variable "counter" and make it counter++ after each addition and do nothing in case of removing element. Otherwise if you need id's in sequence then you must have to reset/update all id's against each removal. I could implement it for you if your code could be simpler, but right now it will take long, so i can suggest only :)

Comment: @Sami thanks for the quick reply but the problem is i need to have addMore button in all the clone could you please how to reset or update thanks in advance

Comment: It would be better to edit your question and include the reason that why you need id's strictly in a sequence (and not using auto-increment approach), plus why you need "Add More" in each row, because without reason it does seem to be a good idea to make things complex for nothing. If you tell your limitation, then yes, its all possible to do it as it is, i will implement it for you, but it is always bad to stick with our initial approach if we have easier/better alternatives. So please add the reasons for both requirements

Comment: Hi @Sami actually that was the Initial approach for this project and they want the same so i have to go like that :(

Comment: Agree with @Sami, adding additional 'addmore' buttons every time you add a new row is misguiding for your users, and it also creates you the problems you mentioned.